# Turn off Vertices in Eevee Mode?

Tags: eevee-render-engine

Is it possible to toggle vertices in eevee mode? I want to edit in one screen and see my model in the other. I know you can do it in cycles.

Here is what I'm talking about:
[image]

Comment: According to [this documentation](https://en.blender.org/index.php/Dev:2.8/Source/Viewport/Overlays) it seems this is what the *overlay* toggle is supposed to do, however it doesn't work on my version (168a6a4bfc1). Might be a bug.